# How to position an item relative to parent Group in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

Like we do `position: relative;` in CSS, I need to position any newly created items relative to the parent `Group`. This is what I expect to get:

[image]

...with the following code:

```js
var path = new Path([50, 0], [50, 100]);
var path2 = new Path([0, 50], [100, 50]);
// cross center at [50, 50]

var center = [100, 100]

var group = new Group({
    children: [path, path2],
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

// It's important to arrange the position 
// right after creating the group
group.translate([50, 50])

new Path.Circle({
    center: center,
    radius: 5,
    fillColor: 'red'
})

new Path.Rectangle({
    from: [10, 10],
    to: [40, 40],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    parent: group
})
```

However, [what I actually get is](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/fVGxbsMgEP2VE0scyUrcKl6oMmXIWrWj7YHgS2yZgHWQdojy7wUMrbKUhTve4713cGdaXJFx9jmhkwMrmTR96L8EwSzcAHvQ+A3vviyauiqh6kqIxUtVdeu3Vmfm6xPVE+pI9bRYBup2C5KMtSBROyQQbpHycKsXpYTs08VgkqELmducTI6hLu6tBr/kMKqeUHNoQpByidOVC2odmQkPRhnisDopIadVqx8hT1TcOBLaKuGwyGHWwTLPsjmMJBX+msWAPO3Jg0Q/3iyHOvXnUansSNhHvyfND5RO6Muf7JnMlYehw8w5ujP+aOePdtV/0yRoFv4NHF/eKTv6Hz0Rimk2o3aW8aZ7/AA=) as follows:

[image]

How can I make newly created items positioned relative to its parent group?

> Note: In order to take the "desired" screenshot, I needed to `.translate()` the `group` after inserting the rectangle: [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/fVExbsMwDPwK4SUuYCRukSwqMmXoWrSj7UGRmdiwQhmU0g5B/l5JllpkqRaRvNPxSN0KkhcsRPE5oVNDURXK9CH/kgyzdAPsgfAb3n1YNru6grqrIAbPdd09vbaUmS8PVE/YRaqnxTBQNxtQbKwFheSQQbpFysMtLUoJ2aeHoUmGzmyuc2ryFuLy1hL4o4ZR94wkoAlGqsVOVy2odWwmPBhtWMDqqKWaVi3dg5+WsuH1YWSl8VcxuhDpTkIs+/FqBexSfhq1zrKMfRR90PxA5SSd/2RPbC4iTBYGy/6c8aWtL23r/ywnaJZ+UCeWZeSOMVk7lmS1dFjmpXrQ/+iRUU6zGcnZQjTd/Qc=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it's controlled by `applyMatrix: false` parameter: [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/jVFNb8IwDP0rVi8FqYJuopdMnDjsNGnajtCDSQ1EDUnlhH0I8d+XtMkmbssltt+L37NzLQyeqRDFe09enoqqkLaL+QcyDOhPsAZDn/Aawtm2qSuo2wrG4KGu2/nTzmTm4x01EJqRGmhjGKnLJUi2zoEk44kB/dQqwDszdUrIOj2MIhk6sr0MSeQ5xrPrzkA48qR0x2QEbKORarLTVhPqPNueNlZbFlDuNcq+TBAOg/5+Qc/qS8ABtaMA3KLTUWvhGY3T6GmWbc6jmTzlYqNYavq1MVoX6U4SjJ26OAFNyg9K6+yFqSuj3l3PN5IezfGv7YHtWcR1xG3kobwNpVUorep/zDlg2I4X0wazYvjrPRP2g1XGu0Js29sP)

```js
var group = new Group({
    children: [path, path2],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    applyMatrix: false,
});
group.translate([50, 50])
```